# When div content reaches and of it's height start showing them on a different column (multiple columns)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something like:

```
<div>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
...this repeats like 80 times
</div>
```

At the main div I have set a height of 30rem. How can I make it so the rests of the divs show on a new column ? Instead of scrolling down

Comment: What have you tried so far? Consider using flexbox, or grid?

Comment: It would be great and helpful if you could share a sample design image of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Column_layouts

Answer (score 1):

Just try with the display flex

```css
.test{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
    <p>...this repeats like 80 times<p>
</div>
```